# Using a batch file, how can I write to a file that has its location stored in a variable?

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a file called "server.cfg" and put it in a location whose path is stored in a variable. I have written the below code to try to accomplish this, but instead of using the variable, the script creates a file called "server" in the same folder as the script.

```
:: Set the data variable with the folder name where server.cfg file will be (check the example)
:: example SET data=server-dataV1
SET data= server-dataV1.2
SET server = %data%\resources\server.cfg

echo # Only change the IP if you're using a server with multiple network interfaces, otherwise change the port only. >> server
echo endpoint_add_tcp "0.0.0.0:30120" >> server
echo endpoint_add_udp "0.0.0.0:30120" >> server
echo >> server
echo set mysql_connection_string "mysql://root:12345@localhost/es_extendedv1?charset=utf8mb4" >> server
echo set mysql_slow_query_warning 200000 >> server
```

Comment: Could you fix the typos, please?

Comment: hi... what typos ?

Comment: maybe a missing "the" between "place" and "location"

Comment: Read the title of your question.

Comment: well after reading it 10 or 15 times i am still unsure where the error might be...
'Using a bat file' --> i think this is self explanatory
'how can i write to a file' --> how to place words/text into such file
'that has is location' --> the location of such file, here "is" it's referring to the file
'on a variable set' --> the location of the file is set on a variable
After reading this 15 times, still unsure where is the mistake

Comment: @Miguel - I have fixed the typos since you couldn't find them.

Comment: about the title yehh the bath error yehh i agree lol sorry... I am unsure about the is/its ... the others i don't see it being wrong , your way is better written definitely, but i do not see my way being that wrong. Anyway thanks

Comment: Remove the _spaces_ around the `=`-signs in the `set` expressions. To read a variable enclose it in `%`-signs, like `%server%`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it isn't clear what you're trying to achieve, so this is my best guess.

```batch-file
@Rem Set the data variable with the folder name where server.cfg file will be (check the example)
@Rem Example: Set "data=server-dataV1"

@Set "data=server-dataV1.2"
@Set "server=%data%\resources\server.cfg"

@(
    Echo # Only change the IP if you're using a server with multiple network interfaces, otherwise change the port only.
    Echo endpoint_add_tcp "0.0.0.0:30120"
    Echo endpoint_add_udp "0.0.0.0:30120"
    Echo=
    Echo set mysql_connection_string "mysql://root:12345@localhost/es_extendedv1?charset=utf8mb4"
    Echo set mysql_slow_query_warning 200000
) 1> "%server%"
```